# Filter separate csv files in Haskell by column?

Tags: csv, haskell, record

I'm learning Haskell and have been having difficulties with creating functions that parse csv files and filter them. I want to write a function(or multiple functions) that take in 2 csv files and compares them to filter out a list of words in the first csv file.

Example CSV file 1 has:

```
ID,State,Desc
1,"Solid",Something
2,"Liquid",Something
4,"Gas",Something
```

And CSV file 2 has:

```
State,Desc,ID
" Not Solid",Something,1
"Plasma",Something,3
"Matter",Something ,5
```

Is it possible to compare the State column from the first csv file with the State column of the second csv file and filter them out so that if a word inside csv2 matches a word inside csv1 then it can be removed so the final output would look something like:

```
ID,State,Desc
2,"Liquid",Something
4,"Gas",Something
```

I've been able to return the columns for each csv file separately but have been unable to save them in Haskell to do the filter later. I was also thinking of hard coding the State column from the second csv file but have had no luck with the function

```
remove :: [Record] -> IO()
 remove csv =  print $ filter (not.any (`elem` csv2)) csv
     where csv2 = ["Not Solid", "Plasma", "Matter"]
```

There are not a ton of csv parsing/processing tips with Haskell so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For parsing CSV people use Cassava https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava But if you can't solve this problem when `csv1` and `csv2` are already parsed lists of records, you should forget about CSV for now and get back to learning list processing in Haskell. E.g. can you write a function that finds a given word in a given list of `Record`s?

Comment: Also, Don't do `print` in the function that searches. Try to decompose the task into several pure list-processing functions. Print only in `main`.